# Time Series with dplyr data frame using ggseas

Tags: r, time-series, dplyr

Hi I have a data frame that was generated with tidyverse and i know there is a ggplot2 extension: ggseas that can work on stl decomposition and create plots of the decomposition: here is the sample data frame:

```
require(dplyr)
sample_dt <- tibble(Year=rep(seq(2012,2016),12),Month=rep(c("M01","M02","M03","M04","M05","M06","M07","M08","M09","M10","M11","M12"),5),ActualDemand=runif(60,min=100,max=6000))
```

I understand from the ggeas help page that the data frame has to be converted to tsdf first, but when i do that, i got the error message of "timeseries needs to be of class ts or mts".

Could anyone give some ideas on how to work on this?

Comment: I you already have a data.frame you don't need to worry about that, as far as I understand. You are not converting to an object of class `tsdf`, you are simply converting to a data.frame. It stands for `time series to data frame`.

Comment: Hi Axeman, thank you very much for your tip. I now realized that I had been understanding exactly the opposite way!

Answer (score 0):

Create a [time series](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ts.html) object

```
sample_ts <- ts(select(sample_dt,-Month),
                start = min(sample_dt$Year), 
                end = max(sample_dt$Year))

plot(sample_ts)
```

Now you have to figure out how to use `library(lubridate)` to add the month and the year in a single date column.

Comment: Thanks Paul, i did some further research and figured out how to use lubridate package to solve the problem and it worked.